# addDomListener event logic?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have the following  code

```
 function init() {
     var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
     var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.949454, 35.932913),
         zoom: 8,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     debugger;
     var mapcity = {};
     mapcity['amman'] = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.949454, 35.932913),
         population: 50000,
         name: 'Amman'
     };
     mapcity['zarqa'] = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.79, 33.39),
         population: 100000,
         name: 'Zarqa'
     };

     for (var city in mapcity) {
         var cityInfo = {
             strokeWeight: 2,
             fillColor: 'cyan',
             center: mapcity[city].center,
             radius: mapcity[city].population,
             map: map,
             strokeOpacity: 0.8,
             fillOpacity: 0.3,

         }
         Circle = new google.maps.Circle(cityInfo)
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(Circle, 'click', function () {
             alert(mapcity[city].name);
         });
     }
 };
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

I want to draw a map with two circles and an event on each circle, but the problem is that the event on click gives the same value for both circles ! it gives the city name for the second city for both circles!!! maybe its because its in the for loop so the  Circle object will always take the last value.
I tried using function with switch statement or IF ELSE but it didn't work!!!

please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

In the anonymous function you close over the city variable, but you keep changing the value of the city variable. You need to freeze it, and the easiest way to do that is to take it as an argument to a function.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(Circle, 'click', (function (city) {
  return function() {
    alert(mapcity[city].name);
  }
})(city));
```